# Proguard Stack in Crashlytics

Tags: android, proguard, crashlytics

I have several recurrent logs in Crashlytics that I can't read.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
   at ahm.onClick(SourceFile:239)
   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4212)
   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17476)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:800)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5431)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

AND

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
   at com.app.mobile.RutaActivity.a(SourceFile:747)
   at ahh.run(SourceFile:1055)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

In the first log, the name of my app's package is never mentioned, so I don't even know where to look for my NPE.

In the second log, I have the FileName (RutaActivity) but when I look at the line number, I see no place for a NPE bug...

How can I do?
How can I do in the second log to see the method name instead of a?

My Proguard file:

```
##---------------Begin: proguard configuration common for all Android apps ----------
-optimizationpasses 5
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers
-dontpreverify
-dump class_files.txt
-printseeds seeds.txt
-printusage unused.txt
-printmapping mapping.txt

-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*

-allowaccessmodification
-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable, LocalVariableTable,LocalVariableTypeTable
-repackageclasses ''


-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper
-keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference
-dontnote com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService

-keep public class * extends android.view.View {
    public <init>(android.content.Context);
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
    public void set*(...);
}

# Explicitly preserve all serialization members. The Serializable interface
# is only a marker interface, so it wouldn't save them.
-keepclassmembers class * implements java.io.Serializable {
    static final long serialVersionUID;
    private static final java.io.ObjectStreamField[] serialPersistentFields;
    private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream);
    private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream);
    java.lang.Object writeReplace();
    java.lang.Object readResolve();
}


# Preserve all native method names and the names of their classes.
-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}
-keepclassmembers class * extends android.content.Context {
   public void *(android.view.View);
   public void *(android.view.MenuItem);
}

-keepclassmembers class * {
    @android.webkit.JavascriptInterface <methods>;
}


-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}


-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}


# Preserve static fields of inner classes of R classes that might be accessed
# through introspection.
-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
  public static <fields>;
}


##---------------End: proguard configuration common for all Android apps ----------


##---------------Begin: proguard configuration for Gson  ----------
# Gson uses generic type information stored in a class file when working with fields. Proguard
# removes such information by default, so configure it to keep all of it.
-keepattributes Signature


# Gson specific classes
-keep class sun.misc.Unsafe { *; }

# Application classes that will be serialized/deserialized over Gson
-keep class com.google.gson.examples.android.model.** { *; }


##---------------End: proguard configuration for Gson  ----------

##---------------Begin proguard configuration for Google Maps --------------------

-keep class com.google.android.gms.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**

-keep class org.** { *; }
-keep class * extends java.util.ListResourceBundle {
    protected Object[][] getContents();
}

-keep public class com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.SafeParcelable {
    public static final *** NULL;
}

-keepnames @com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName class *
-keepclassmembernames class * {
    @com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName *;
}


-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable

##---------------End proguard configuration for Google Maps --------------------

##---------------Begin proguard configuration for my libs  -----------------------
-keep class com.todddavies.components.progressbar.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.todddavies.components.progressbar.**

-dontwarn org.apache.**

-keepclassmembers class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
    static ** CREATOR;
}

#Disable logging

-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
    public static *** d(...);
    public static *** v(...);
    public static *** i(...);
}
-keep class com.app.mobile.vo.Captura { *; }
-keep class com.app.mobile.vo.Formulario { *; }
-keep class com.app.mobile.vo.Metrica { *; }
-keep class com.app.mobile.vo.Pdv { *; }
-keep class com.app.mobile.vo.Proyecto { *; }
-keep class com.app.mobile.vo.Producto { *; }
-keep class com.app.mobile.vo.Nota { *; }
-keep class com.app.mobile.vo.Encuesta { *; }
-keep class com.app.mobile.vo.Usuario { *; }
-keep class com.app.mobile.vo.BambooPerf { *; }
-keep class com.app.mobile.vo.SoftwareVersion { *; }
```

Comment: use `retrace.jar` with the mapping file from proguard to recreate a readable stacktrace : http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/retrace/examples.html

Comment: also, crashlytics is supposed to be able to read stacktraces, provided that you give it the mappings.txt file with the apk

Comment: Have you tried removing `-printmapping mapping.txt` from your Proguard file?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I contact Crashlytics support, and I resolved the problem!

They told me to check Crashlytics.log:

On ﻿Linux / Windows:
~/.crashlytics/com.crashlytics.tools/crashlytics.log

﻿On Mac:
﻿~/Library/Caches/com.crashlytics/﻿com.crashlytics.tools/crashlytics.log﻿

Here I saw that:

```
Crashlytics detected deobfuscation, but did not find a mapping file at /Users/admin/AndroidstudioProjects/MyApp/build/outputs/mapping/release/mapping.txt
```

So I just changed

```
-printmapping mapping.txt
```

to

```
-printmapping build/outputs/mapping/release/mapping.txt
```

and it worked!

Tx for you help !

Comment: Thanks for update. This issue was driving me crazy as I had setup everything but still the code was obfuscated on the crashlytics site

Comment: This is the right answer, but I should add that it doesn't work if you're using product flavors. Deleting the -printmapping line should be a better option in this case.

Comment: We should remove -printmapping  from proguard file. reference link https://docs.fabric.io/android/crashlytics/dex-and-proguard.html,

Comment: @Dharmendra wouldn't it prevent us from having proper source file names if we use "-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile" at the same time?

Answer (score 6):

I just have the following 2 lines in my Proguard file for Crashlytics:

```
-keep class com.crashlytics.** { *; }
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to what @Dharmendra mentioned, in the current version of Crashlytics, [their documentation](https://docs.fabric.io/android/crashlytics/dex-and-proguard.html) says:

> For Fabric to properly de-obfuscate your crash reports, you need to **remove** this line from your configuration file, or we won’t be able to automatically upload your mapping file:
>
> -printmapping mapping.txt

Also, if you include code in your own Android library which is used by your parent project, make sure to remove this in both the project's and the library's proguard-rules.pro files (this was my issue).